# Euclid's Perpendicular Postulate

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Is there a form of non-Euclidean geometry in which perpendicular lines never cross, or cross twice or something?

Answer (score 1):

Perpendicular lines are by definition those that *meet* at a right angle. Hence "never cross" is impossible. 
Non-Euclidean geometries are those that differ in the variation of the parallel postulate; especially, it holds in all of them that two distinct points determine a line so that "cross twice" is also impossible.

Comment: Should be "two distinct points determine a *unique* line so that cross twice is also impossible" It's the uniqueness that makes it impossible :)

Comment: Lines in spherical geometry meet twice. Oh sure, we can define "point" to include is antipode, but it's an obvious rule patch.